# How to give href a location outside my domain?

Tags: asp.net, href

```
        <a target="_blank" href='www.twitter.com/<%#Eval("FromUser") %>'> 
           <asp:Image ID="userImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Profile") %>' />
         </a>
```

When I click on the image, I'm redirected to 
"http://localhost:49898/www.twitter.com/blablabla"

How can I remove "http://localhost:49898/"  this part from my href ?

Comment: have you tried to place http:// ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `http://` to your anchor:

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.twitter.com/<%#Eval("FromUser") %>'> 
    <asp:Image ID="userImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Profile") %>' />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

put protocol in front. try http://twitter.com ...

Answer (score 2):

try this :

> href='http://www.twitter.com/<%#Eval("FromUser") %>'

Answer (score 2):

because you are not specified http ,that means it is not getting the protocol name for where it has to search or it is not getting DNS server, thats why it redirecting to by default localhost. use http in front of anchor.

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.twitter.com/<%#Eval("FromUser") %>'> 
           <asp:Image ID="userImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Profile") %>' />
         </a>
```